# How to create weekly raster mosaics?

Tags: r, image, gis, raster

I'm working with some Copernicus data (soil moisture product, temoporal resolution - 1 day). I have downloaded all available data for 2021 (collection of 365 images). Is it possible to create mosaics which are created from 7 consecutive days and then form next 7 days and next 7 days and so on? For example, 1-7 of January, 8-14 of January...
Honestly, I have no idea how to do it, so only code with file path below:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)

setwd("E:/igik/ssm")
getwd()
path<-getwd()

export<-file.path("E:/igik/ssm_mosaic")

r1 <- raster("E:/igik/ssm/c_gls_SSM1km-ssm_201901010000_CUSTOM_S1CSAR_V1.1.1.tiff")

r1
 
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 771, 1280, 986880  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008928571, 0.008928571  (x, y)
extent     : 13.3125, 24.74107, 48.41071, 55.29464  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : c_gls_SSM1km-ssm_201901010000_CUSTOM_S1CSAR_V1.1.1.tiff 
names      : c_gls_SSM1km.ssm_201901010000_CUSTOM_S1CSAR_V1.1.1 
values     : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

Folder with images ("E:/igik/ssm_mosaic") contains 365 single-band tiffs (1 image-1 day). Files are named like:

- c_gls_SSM1km-ssm_201901010000_CUSTOM_S1CSAR_V1.1.1.tiff
- c_gls_SSM1km-ssm_201901020000_CUSTOM_S1CSAR_V1.1.1.tiff
- c_gls_SSM1km-ssm_201901030000_CUSTOM_S1CSAR_V1.1.1.tiff

Only date is changing.

Comment: Could you provide the shape of your data please? That would help in order to create the desired output.

Comment: I added some info about data. I hope it helps.